# When to use "settings-security.xml" and when not in Maven

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver

Can someone help me to understand when to use "settings-security.xml" and when not in Maven projects ?
I Know it stores encrypted master password which then used to decrypt password in "Settings.xml" file but not sure why few companies(I worked for) use only settings.xml and few uses both.
Anyhow "Settings.xml" going to be stored in user directory under .m2, so no one else can access it except the user then why to go extra mile for "settings-security.xml"

I searched in Stack overflow under maven section, Referred Maven official site, Googled a lot. Everywhere I see the what does Setting-Security xml does and what settings.xml does but I still have doubt how few big companies manages just with "settings.xml" but not "settings-security.xml"

Comment: You could allow others to read the settings.xml file.

Comment: In Maven `security.xml` does not exist. Only `settings-security.xml`.  `https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html It's not an extra mile typically you configure maven to encrypt passwords/keys for accessing remote repos etc. In Corporate environment you don't store credentials in `settings.xml` that is done via CI/CD tools like Jenkins etc. So most of the time on CI/Cd the `settings-security.xml` is not used.

Comment: My bad, instead of settings.xml I mistyped as security.xml which i corrected now @khmarbaise, thank you for pointing out. Settings.xml will have repository details, mirror details, server username, password, etc.. I agree, then what is the use of settings-security.xml ? Is it just there to encrypt the password present in settings.xml ? If yes, I have seen in few companies that they just used settings.xml why not the settings-security ?

Comment: If settings.xml is used only does mean no encryption.. only local storage (home directory of the user or via ci/cd config file provider) ...

Comment: So you mean to say when only Settings.xml  used, the password in that should be raw and not encrypted ?

Comment: I referred the link - https://blog.sonatype.com/2009/10/maven-tips-and-tricks-encrypting-passwords/ and got clear picture on the difference between settings.xml ans settings-security.xml